# How to combine several multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are a do-while loop that for each new pass creates a new array.

---

A **do-while** loop:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    //  Create an array of data from the response
        $array_data = array();

        foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
            $created_time = $data['created_time'];              
            $thumbnail = $data['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
            $tags_name = $get_TagIMG;

            $array_data[] = array
            (
                'DATE_PIC' => $created_time,
                'LINK_PIC' => $thumbnail,
                'TAG_PIC' => $tags_name,
            );
        }   
    $i++;

    } while ($i < 5);
```

---

After the end of the cycle, we get five arrays, such as the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380488912 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/4c39144e294b11e3bef022000a1f9245_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380489222 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/04ca9032294c11e3b53822000a1f96e6_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380492460 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/8e755dd8295311e3a53722000aeb43de_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380718591 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/0f8bcf142b6211e3982822000ae90f30_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)

Array (
    [4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380717412 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/507c69fa2b5f11e3a7d422000a9e0846_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

---

Question: How to combine these arrays into one?

---

the result should be something like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380488912 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/4c39144e294b11e3bef022000a1f9245_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380489222 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/04ca9032294c11e3b53822000a1f96e6_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380492460 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/8e755dd8295311e3a53722000aeb43de_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380718591 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/0f8bcf142b6211e3982822000ae90f30_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
    [4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1380717412 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/507c69fa2b5f11e3a7d422000a9e0846_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => pricelessmoscow )
)
```

Comment: You mean, you have 5 arrays in $array_data, that you have var_dumped? How do you want to combine them?

Comment: Are you sure this specific listing provides this specific situation?!?

Comment: @user4035 complements question

Comment: @archi_sova Why are you running this do while loop? $i is never used anywhere in your code.

Comment: Actually, You wouldn't end up with 5 arrays after the loop, you will end up with one, as you are overwriting your `$array_data` value each time.

Comment: Friends, I know what I'm saying, I just need to merge arrays, and all... :) Please tell me how to do it

Comment: Maybe you do know what you're saying but we (at least I) don't.

Comment: I wrote that I want to see the end... **the result should be something like:**

Comment: I _know_ what you want. I think everyone does. Before getting a definitive answer, I think you should _try_ to ask a question that is at least _consistent_. I'm tired of waiting, so -1 for demanding an answer without _helping us to help you_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source code seems to be correct, is that exactly what you're running?

And, if you want to go over all of your objects, not just `N`, you can use a `foreach()`:

```
<?php

    // used to populate
    $sourceData = array(1,2,3);

    // array of arrays
    $data = array();

    foreach( $sourceData as $val )
    {
        $data[] = array( "date" => "date_" . $val,
                         "link" => "link_" . $val,
                         "tag"  => "tag_"  . $val );
    }

    var_dump($data);    

?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "date_1"
    ["link"]=>
    string(6) "link_1"
    ["tag"]=>
    string(5) "tag_1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "date_2"
    ["link"]=>
    string(6) "link_2"
    ["tag"]=>
    string(5) "tag_2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "date_3"
    ["link"]=>
    string(6) "link_3"
    ["tag"]=>
    string(5) "tag_3"
  }
}
```

Comment: @archi_sova: Not sure what you're asking. That's an array of arrays in my example.

Comment: how to apply to my example? )